# Error-slf4j-error try to get loggers

Tags: slf4j, javaagents

I am getting following error when I am trying to use loggers for Java class

```
%PARSER_ERROR_d [%PARSER_ERROR_thread] %PARSER_ERROR_level %PARSER_ERROR_logger - %PARSER_ERROR_msg%PARSER_ERROR_n%PARSER_ERROR_d [%PARSER_ERROR_thread] %PARSER_ERROR_level %PARSER_ERROR_logger - %PARSER_ERROR_msg%PARSER_ERROR_n
```

This is my code where i try to use logs .

```
 public class MyAdvice {

    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    static void get(@Advice.Origin String method) {

        System.out.println(method);
        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Logs");
        log.info("INFO");
    }
}
```

Any suggestion for this problem.